# Part 2 - Creating Groups with Dplyr's "group_by" then Using Stringr's "str_detect" to Find Differences Between Groups

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

This is a more complex example of a previous question - [Creating Groups with Dplyr's "group_by" then Using Stringr to Find Differences Between Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40599571/3817004).

I would like to continue using `dplyr` and `stringr` if possible, or at least stay within the Tidyverse.

In this more complex example, I once again need to group the data by CaseWorker and Client and compare "Task" and "Task2" to find all the categories in "Task2" that are not in "Task". There is also a "Time" column.

"Task" can have categories that are not in "Task2", so I'm only interested in finding categories in "Task2" that are not in "Task". It would be great to be able to create a new column or dataframe to show the specific entry that is in "Task2" and not in "Task", along with the associated "Time" value.

The end result should show "Iron shirt" and "Do homework" for client "Chris" since both those categories are not in "Task", and should show the total "Time" for each.

For client "Eric", it should show "Iron shirt" and the "Time" of 12.

```
CaseWorker<-c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John",
"John","Kim","Kim")

Client<-c("Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Eric","Eric")

Task<-c("Feed cat","Feed cat","Feed cat","Make dinner","Make dinner","Make dinner","Buy groceries","Buy groceries","Buy groceries","Do homework","Do homework")

Task2<-c("Feed cat","Iron shirt","Iron shirt","Do Homework","Do homework","Do homework","Make dinner","Feed cat","Feed cat","Do homework","Iron shirt")

Time<-c(20,34,11,10,5,6,55,30,20,10,12)

Df<-data.frame(CaseWorker,Client,Task,Task2,Time)
```

Comment: Can you update with the expected output?  Perhaps `library(data.table);setDT(Df)[, setdiff(Task2, Task) , by = .(CaseWorker, Client)]`

Comment: I tried to explain the output towards the end. As for the exact output, I'm actually not quite sure since it will depend on what's possible. I suppose the best would be an extra column that shows "Iron shirt" and "Do homework" for Chris, along with the total "Time" for each, and "Iron shirt" for client Eric, along with the "Time" of 12.

Comment: Another option, if it's possible, is to collapse the categories so each is only displayed once, for example, for client Chris, it would show "Feed cat", "Make dinner","Buy groceries". Same for the "Task2" column with a total "Time". Then continue with what I wrote in the comment above...

Comment: You can paste them `setDT(Df)[, toString(setdiff(Task2, Task)) , by = .(CaseWorker, Client)]`

Comment: I would like to stick with piping and dplyr and stringr. There is a similar question, same title without the "part 2", which is a simpler example and shows the kind of responses I received. I would like something similar to these if possible!

Comment: If you want `dplyr`, then `Df %>% group_by(CaseWorker, Client) %>% summarise(New = toString(setdiff(Task2, Task)))` or may be `Df %>% group_by(CaseWorker, Client) %>% summarise(New = toString(setdiff(tolower(Task2), tolower(Task))))`

Comment: Thanks! I love the use of setdiff, I didn't think of that, partly because I'm fairly new to set operations. I tried it and it works great. I can accept the answer if you provide an official answer. Also, is there a way to include the "Time" column so that it provides the total summarised time? This way, the total time for client Chris would be 66. (the sum of "Do homework" and "Iron shirt", and the sum for client Eric is 12, for "Iron shirt". This is more of a bonus if possible. If it's too much, the original answer without the "Time" column is fine. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Thanks, I posted a solution with the additional Time column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the elements in 'Task2' that are not in 'Task' using `setdiff`, `paste` them together with `toString` (wrapper for `paste(..., collapse=', ')`) after grouping by 'CaseWorker' and 'Client'

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>% 
   group_by(CaseWorker, Client) %>% 
   summarise(New = toString(setdiff(Task2, Task)))
```

---

If we need the `sum` of 'Time' column for the subset elements of 'Task2', `filter` the 'Task2' before the `summarise` step

```
Df %>%
   group_by(CaseWorker, Client) %>%
   filter(Task2 %in% setdiff(Task2, Task)) %>% 
   summarise(New= toString(unique(Task2)), Time = sum(Time))
#    CaseWorker Client                                  New  Time
#        <fctr> <fctr>                                <chr> <dbl>
#1         John  Chris Iron shirt, Do Homework, Do homework    66
#2          Kim   Eric                           Iron shirt    12
```

There are elements in 'Task2' that have case differences.  If that needs to be sorted out, convert to either lower or upper, get the `unique` elements and `paste` it together i.e.   `New= toString(unique(tolower(Task2)))` in the `summarise` step.

Comment: Quick question, instead of showing the combined time in the example above (66) for Client Chris, is there a way to show the time broken up for "Iron Shirt" and "Do Homework"? For example, if I then wanted to use Tidyr's separate to break apart the string into different columns (Iron shirt and Do Homework, and then have the time for each). If it's really complicated, I can create a new question...

Comment: @Mike Can you create as a new question

Comment: I created the new question - titled "Creating Groups with Dplyr's “group_by” then Using Stringr or Set Operations to Find Differences Between Groups". Let me know if you have a better title suggestion lol, I'm struggling to give it an accurate title...